# What does the hyperref option hypertexnames do?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, links, package-options

The [Manual of `hyperref`](http://tug.org/applications/hyperref/ftp/doc/manual.html) states that `hypertexnames`: *use guessable names for links*.

What does this mean? What are the consequences of using this option?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With the option `hypertexnames` hyperref uses the corresponding counter in addition to the link type to construct the link name. Imagine, you have two chapters and one section in each chapter plus one table. The link names would be:

With `hypertexnames`:

```
chapter.1
section.1.1
table.1.1
chapter.2
section.2.1
```

Without `hypertexnames`:

```
chapter.3
section.4
table.5
chapter.6
section.7
```

Without `hypertexnames` it's just counting upwards, using the `\Hy@linkcounter` instead of the corresponding chapter resp. section counter. It's similar for other objects and links to them.

Thus, with `hypertexnames` you could guess the link name, if you would like to use it for referencing, from the corresponding counter value instead of a shared counter.

Looking for `hypertexnames` in hyperref.sty gives further information, for instance in the definition of the command `\hyper@makecurrent`. But you could also take a quick look into the .aux, .toc, .lot etc. files to notice the different kind of link names.

Comment: The counting done with `hypertexnames` enabled (which is the default) can get you into troubles if you are e.g. resetting chapter counters for the various parts of your book. The counting done with `hypertexnames=false` isn't "guessable", but more robust. Check out [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6098)...