# Wrong (hyper-)references after resetting chapter counter

Tags: hyperref, counters

The following MWE produces a PDF whose TOC has two entries: “Foo” and “Bar” with correct page numbers. So far, so good. However, upon clicking on the link to “Bar”, I am taken to the page for “Foo” instead.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*\backmatter{\setcounter{chapter}{0}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\backmatter
\chapter{Bar}
\end{document}
```

(Produced with `pdflatex`, run twice.)

This MWE is whittled down from a (*much*!) more complex document but the above does seem to reproduce the error reliably.

Re-setting the chapter count seems to confuse hyperref, even though the page references are still accurate. Notice that in my real document, `\backmatter` does other things, including setting the numbering style to alphabetical so there’s no chance of confusion even though both chapters are ostensibly labelled as “Chapter 1”.

**How do I fix this?** Is this a bug? Are there workarounds?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Hyperref is just too clever sometimes. Make it dumber, and hence more robust:

```
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Wow, this actually works, *and* makes sense. But it’s not guessable from the documentation’s description of the option. Documentation fail. :-(

Comment: This helped me with *hyperref* getting its PDF bookmarks all tangled up because I was resetting chapter numbering in my book parts. +1!

Comment: +1 well deserved! Got my problem in scientific workplace fixed where my hiërarchy got totally messed up.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I can confirm this works having stumbled into the same problem and used the same fix, but how in the world does this make sense? :(

Comment: @ffledgling Look at Ulrike’s answer: by default, `hyperref` derives internal link identifiers based on chapter numbers. However, when using different sections, there are two chapters with number 1. So by making `hyperref` dumber, we force it to adopt internal consecutive identifiers, rather than identifiers that map to actual chapter numbering.

Comment: Had a document I reset the counter every chapter and the hyperrefs weirdly kept linking back to chapter 1 labels even though I told it to go to chapte 2 labels. This fixed my issues.

Comment: This helped me, too, fix flaky links to the wrong chapter for a book (memoir class) where I have a Chapter 0 as the initial chapter and in addition use zref to allow references to another section n within a chapter m to be in the form "Section n" rather than the default "Section m.n".

Answer (score 16):

You have two chapter 1. Naturally this confuse hyperref. You must give the internal counter a unique "look". E.g.:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*\backmatter{%
 \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
 \renewcommand\theHchapter{back.\arabic{chapter}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\backmatter
\chapter{Bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Naturally. ;-) But I *did* originally set `\thechapter` without effect. And `\theHchapter` doesn’t even appear in the documentation (nor does any other occurrence of ‘`theH`’, according to `grep`).