# Error while writing Japanese characters

Tags: errors, undefined, japanese

I want to add a Japanese character in front of a chapter. But it is showing an error, Latin alphabets and numbers work fine.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{CJKutf8} %for japanese characters

\begin{document}

 
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thechapter{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min} 
    的 % character to appear before the chapter title
    \end{CJK}}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display] %error here: Undefined control sequence.  Argument of 
                                                 %\@xdblarg has an extra }.
                                       
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{20pt}{\Huge}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \endgroup

\end{document}
```

The desired output that I want is

[image]

Also before this chapter, the following is shown, which I want to remove
[image]

Comment: You seem to be using the `titlesec` package (for `\titleformat`) but this doesn't appear in your MWE. Furthermore, with this command you have explicitly said that you _don't_ want your chapter names labelled. If you put `\thechapter` inside the empty pair of braces (before `{20pt}`) does that produce what you want?

Comment: @Ant this is what I followed https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50949/284954 Also no, your suggestion doesn't work but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{CJKutf8} %for japanese characters

\usepackage{lipsum} % let's show the headers

\NewDocumentCommand{\nihonchars}{m}{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}#1\end{CJK}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{\nihonchars{的} Introduction}
\markboth{\nihonchars{的} \MakeUppercase{Introduction}}
  {\nihonchars{的} \MakeUppercase{Introduction}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nihonchars{的} Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

#### TOC

[image]

#### Chapter page

[image]

#### Header

[image]

Comment: Extremely sorry for the confusion, I have updated the post please refer to it.

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist Is the new version what you want?

Comment: The chapter name in TOC and header is still showing "1 Introduction", is there any way to change it?

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist Would you please, in the future, specify all that you need? See the edited answer.

Comment: Yes, I will, thank you very much for putting up with me. I realize that it can be annoying to edit the answer again and again but I genuinely had no idea that headers and TOC won't be affected. But as you said, to prevent this I will declare clearly what I want. Thank you once again for being patient with me.