# How do I get two different chapters with same number, and compatible references (using hyperref)?

Tags: hyperref, amsbook

I'd be glad if somebody can help me resolving the following issue. Basically, hyperref is confused by my code.

I want the following document structure.

```
Chapter 1
Chapter 2 
Solutions to Exercises 
   | 
   + - Chapter 1
   | 
   + - Chapter 2
Index
Bibliography
```

Here is a minimal (non-)working example (I know why this will not work, but, I am unsure how to fix).

```
\documentclass{amsbook} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeindex 
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \title{A Book} 
    \author{Me} 
    \maketitle

    \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter 
    \chapter{Chapter 1} 
    \chapter{Chapter 2} 

    \part*{Solution to Exercises} 
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \chapter{Chapter 1} 
    \chapter{Chapter 2} 

    \backmatter
    \printindex
    \bibliography 
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit.** The question is not a duplicate of the previous question. It does answer a part of the question however. The remaining parts:

1. The index is not being printed.
2. The index and bibliography are now subbookmarks of the bookmark "Solutions to Exercises".

Any help, atleast through comments, will be very helpful.

Comment: See: [Wrong (hyper-)references after resetting chapter counter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6098/wrong-hyper-references-after-resetting-chapter-counter)

Comment: Doing `\renewcommand\theHchapter{solutions\arabic{chapter}}` solves the issue. Add also `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\noindent{}}` after loading `hyperref` to avoid an unrelated warning.

Comment: @egreg I am afraid this does not sort the back matter properly: the bibliography and index are part of the "Solutions" book mark, as opposed to being outside the fold...

Comment: Also, the index is not being printed!! :(

Comment: Did the linked question help?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Yes. But, please see my edit. (I have voted to reopen as my question is not fully resolved.) Thanks for the help.

Comment: The problem with the bookmarks is dealt with by the `bookmark` package (look for `startatroot`).

Comment: @egreg Thank you! The issue has been sorted out, with the help of several answers on the site. So, perhaps, this is indeed  a duplicate.