# Why might I not want to set naturalnames and hypertexnames both equal to false in hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, pdf

I know from [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3188/what-does-the-hyperref-option-hypertexnames-do) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6098/wrong-hyper-references-after-resetting-chapter-counter) that you can solve a lot of internal linking problems in your PDF by setting naturalnames and hypertexnames both equal to false (naturalnames being set to false by default). So what kinds of problems might I have if I set both of those keys to false?

If it matters, I make a PDF by first making a .ps file from the .dvi file via dvips, then making a .pdf file from the .ps file via Acrobat Distiller. I generally assume that if I have no unusual messages in my .log file and don't get a warning from Distiller about names in Name Tree Dests being defined more than once, then all my internal links work.