# How to fix hyperref when using invisible parts

Tags: hyperref, numbering

I want to create a document with the following structure:

- Part 1 (English Version):

  - Section 1
  - Section 2 etc.
  - Appendix A
  - Appendix B
- Part 2 (German Version):

  - Section 1
  - Section 2 etc.
  - Appendix A
  - Appendix B

I don't want the document to show the "Part 1" headings.
This is why I introduced an "invisiblepart" which restarts the numbering of sections.

Unfortunately, the hyperrefs all lead into Part 1 (see code below).

How can I fix this **hyperref-Problem**?

---

```
\documentclass{amsart}
  \makeatletter
    \@addtoreset{section}{part} 
  \makeatother
  \newcommand\invisiblepart[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
  }
  \usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \invisiblepart{English Version}
    \section{First English section}
       \label{sec11} Goto English Appendix \ref{app11}\pagebreak
    {\appendix\section{First English Appendix}
       \label{app11} Goto English Chapter \ref{sec11}\pagebreak}
  \invisiblepart{German Version}
    \section{First German Section}
       \label{sec21} Goto German Appendix \ref{app21}\pagebreak
    {\appendix\section{First German Appendix}
       \label{app21}Goto German Section \ref{sec21}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6098/wrong-hyper-references-after-resetting-chapter-counter):

> Hyperref is just too clever sometimes. Make it dumber, and hence more robust:
>
> ```
> \usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Page 39 of the `hyperref` [manual](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) says for the `amsrefs`:

> Package loading order:
> `\usepackage{hyperref}`
> `\usepackage{amsrefs}`

It may be the same for `amsart` :)