# cross-reference with improper link

Tags: hyperref, cleveref

In the MWE below, the first and second references link to eq. (I.1), and the third and fourth equation references both link to eq. (2.1).
While they should link to eq. (I.1), (1.1), (II.1) and (2.1), respectively.

What causes this error here?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,pdfencoding=auto, psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\numberwithin{equation}{part}
\part{I}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:I_1}
a = b
\end{equation}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\chapter{I}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:chap_1}
a = part 1
\end{equation}

\numberwithin{equation}{part}
\part{II}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:II_1}
a = chap 1
\end{equation}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\chapter{2}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:chap_2}
a = chap 2
\end{equation}


\cref{eq:I_1}, \cref{eq:chap_1}, \cref{eq:II_1}, \cref{eq:chap_2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Some times the older `.aux` files are not updated appropriately. In the same directory of your `.tex` file, there is a file with the same name and ends with `.aux`. Remove it and try to compile the document again.

Comment: @moewe You are right, I misread the question.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6098/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3188/35864. `hypertexnames=false` could also help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hyperref interally names the links after your \numberwithin commands as `equation.\theHpart.\arabic{equation}` and `equation.\theHchapter.\arabic{equation}`.
As `\theHpart` is defined as `\arabic{part}` and `\theHchapter` as `\arabic{chapter}` this  leads to duplicated destination names. So you get warnings in the log:

```
l.102 \begin{equation}
                      pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifi
er (name{equation.2.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again>
```

One solution is e.g. to change `\theHpart` so that an unique destination is created:

```
 \renewcommand\theHpart{\Roman{part}}
```