# Separating/unnumbering preliminary chapters using classicthesis

Tags: numbering, chapters, classicthesis

I am currently writing my PhD manuscript using classicthesis. So far I have a normal structure, ie

- Title
- TOC
- List of figures
- List of tables
- 4 parts labeled with roman numbers (I to IV), with chapters ranging from 1 to 10 (ca. 2 per part)
- An appendix, labeled part V, with 5 chapters labeled A,B,C,D and E.

It's all in English, but my university demands that I write a 50 page "summary" at the beginning in French. I want to put this before parts I to IV, along with a foreword in English. The problem I have is that I do not want to mess up my chapters; I still want the current Chapter 1 to remain Chapter 1, but with 50 pages to write in French I have to structure them in chapters too. How can I achieve this in the classicthesis package ?

I have tried defining \chapter*{Chapter name}, but it doesn't appear on the TOC and the header doesn't change in each page either. I have also tried to add things in the TOC by hand, but then some things are messed up.

Ideally I would like to pick a custom numbering for the chapters at first (label them using i, ii, iii,iv and so on), and then go back to a standard numbering for chapters (1,2...) after the summary.

I tried this by doing e.g.

```
\renewcommand\thepart{\alph{part}}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\roman{chapter}}
```

before the summaries, and the undoing those changes and resetting the counters as

```
\renewcommand\thepart{\Roman{part}}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\setcounter{part}{0}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
```

before the body, but I found that when I did \setcounter it removed all the parts from the pdf's "contents" list.

Any help ?

Comment: OFT: your university should provide you with a template.

Comment: What I did in my case was that I used unnumbered chapter (`\chapter*{French 50 page summary}`) just after the abstract in English (which is unnumbered chapter itself), in which sections were what chapters are in the rest of the thesis. Resetting chapter numbers is bad, but if you really want it, when you're done with French just set `\setcounter{chapter}{0}`. You could also make the French part a separate pdf and include it in your thesis (adjusting only page numbers). I don't understand why you were resetting part numbers.

Comment: Resetting chapter numbers seems to confuse hyperref package, probably because of the labels/anchors that have the same name for different chapters.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6098/wrong-hyper-references-after-resetting-chapter-counter

Comment: @PhilipPirrip thanks a lot ! The hypperref fix worked :)