# Reset section counter in each appendices environment

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, appendices

I am trying to create the following simple document structure (but with more than just two parts) with `scrartcl`:

[image: Document structure]

I use `\counterwithin*{section}{part}` to number sections within parts.
For the appendices, I expected the `appendix` package to be the solution:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\counterwithin*{section}{part}

\begin{document}

\part{First Part}
\section{First Section} \label{sec:first-first}
\section{Second Section}

\begin{appendices}
    \section{First Appendix} \label{sec:app-first-first}
    \section{Second Appendix}
\end{appendices}

\part{Second Part}
\section{First Section} \label{sec:second-first}
\section{Second Section}
\begin{appendices}
    \section{First Appendix} \label{sec:app-second-first}
    \section{Second Appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

**The Problem**: This seems to ignore the `\counterwithin`. The first appendix in Part II (`sec:app-second-first`) is numbered "C", not "A" as expected.

**What I've tried**:

1. Explicitly adding `\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\counterwithin*{section}{part}}` has no effect.
2. I also tried to avoid the `appendix` package and just add `\setcounter{section}{0} \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}` before and `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` after each appendix, but this confuses `hyperref`: `sec:app-first-first` and `sec:app-second-first` will both jump to `sec:first-first`.
3. [update] I figured out that the workaround from (2) combined with [hypertexnames=false](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6102/37118) works ([full MWE](https://gist.github.com/ClaudiusL/2d3c1526a9c0fc7325f2d68740129bd2)), but as using the `appendices` environment seems to be the "cleaner" and [recommended](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-appendix) solution, I'd still like to know how to tweak the numbering within `appendices`.

**Question:** How can I reset the section counter in each `appendices` environment (without breaking hyperref)?

Comment: Add `\counterwithin*{@ppsaveapp}{part}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you, seems to work like a charm! Would you mind posting this as an answer (maybe even with some explanation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appendix package adds a couple of new counters: `@ppsaveapp` and `@ppsavesec`.  I tried `\counterwithin` on both of them, but only `@ppsaveapp` made a difference.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\counterwithin*{section}{part}
\counterwithin*{@ppsaveapp}{part}

\begin{document}

\part{First Part}
\section{First Section} \label{sec:first-first}
\section{Second Section}

\begin{appendices}
    \section{First Appendix} \label{sec:app-first-first}
    \section{Second Appendix}
\end{appendices}

\part{Second Part}
\section{First Section} \label{sec:second-first}
\section{Second Section}
\begin{appendices}
    \section{First Appendix} \label{sec:app-second-first}
    \section{Second Appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `\appendix` instead of `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}` may solve your problem.

Full working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\counterwithin*{section}{part}

\begin{document}

\part{First Part}
\section{First Section} \label{sec:first-first}
\section{Second Section}

\begin{appendices}
    \section{First Appendix} \label{sec:app-first-first}
    \section{Second Appendix}
\end{appendices}

\part{Second Part}
\section{First Section} \label{sec:second-first}
\section{Second Section}
\appendix
\section{First Appendix} \label{sec:app-second-first}
\section{Second Appendix}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! However, this only solves the special case of exactly 2 parts (which, admittedly, I presented in the question) but cannot address the general case with >2 parts.