# Where can I find out what various hyperref options do?

Tags: hyperref, package-options, tutorials

Where can I find a description of `hyperref` options, deeper than the one of the manual?
I do not understand the meaning of several options.  For instance, what is "redefines LaTeX internals" (option `implicit`), or "use guessable names for links" (option `hypertexnames`)?

Comment: Regarding those "guessable names", have a look at: [What does the hyperref option hypertexnames do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3188/what-does-the-hyperref-option-hypertexnames-do)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Thanks to both.  About the `hypertexnames` option, that was just an example.  I would like a freely available and full description of all the `hyperref` options.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my opinion, such a detailed and user-friendly reference is lacking, for sure.

If you are interested in descriptions that are "deeper than the one of the manual" - and by "manual" I assume you are referring to the user-friendly [`hyperref` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) - then your next available option would be the detailed (and perhaps cryptic) [`hyperref` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.pdf). My choice of names here is completely opposite to that of the filenames on CTAN...

The `hyperref` manual is literally a PDF version of the `.dtx` sources and is therefore filled with code (almost 17,000 lines of it, or just under 400 pages) and sparse comments.

For example, section **28 Automated LaTeX hypertext cross-reference** (p 152) contains a more detailed discussion on the option `hypertexnames`. However, this is probably one of the few detailed discussion on options. The only alternative in my opinion is to keep the [`hyperref` package options summary](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/options.pdf) close by and search the manual for  the relevant code that describes it.