# Wrong links in bibliography using hyperref with options pagebackref and hypertexnames=false

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, links, back-referencing

I am using the `hyperref` package (v6.82m) with MiKTeX 2.9.  I am using the option `pagebackref` so as to obtain a bibliography with links to the pages where the references are cited.  I am also using the option `hypertexnames=false` because a comment in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3188/10072) says that it is more robust.  Although links in the bibliography show the right page numbers, they point to wrong pages (correct page minus 2).  Other page links within the document are ok.  I think this is related to the fact that the `\titlepage` I am using resets page numbers (I have another page before the `\titlepage`).  However, changing `\pagenumbering` before and after `\titlepage` does not solve the problem.  If I suppress the `hypertexnames=false` option, the problem disappears.   Why is this happening?  Is this a bug in the `backref` package?

```
\documentclass{report}

% wrong links in bib
\usepackage[pagebackref, hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

% right links in bib
%\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
     \pagenumbering{roman}
     Some stuff to mess things up a bit more.
     \begin{titlepage}
          Title page
     \end{titlepage}
     \pagenumbering{arabic}
     This is page 1 \cite{X}.
     \newpage
     This is page 2 \cite{X}.

     \begin{thebibliography}{1}

     \bibitem{X}
     Very important paper.

     \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A suggestion and a comment. First, it would be helpful if you provided a Minimum Working Example (MWE) of the code that is giving you trouble. Relatedly, it would be helpful if you indicated which TeX distribution you use. Second, the question/answer you link to in your question is well over a year old by now; fortunately, the `hyperref` and `backref` packages have gone through several updates/improvements/bug fix cycles in the meantime, and hence the advice that was valid back then may no longer be applicable as of now. Which version of the `hyperref` package do you use?

Comment: `hyperref` version is v6.82m. I will try to produce a MWE. I think that even the cited question is old, the links to pages in the bibliography should work fine with both `hypertexnames=true` and `hypertexnames=false`.