# Difference between hypertexnames and naturalnames in hyperref

Tags: hyperref

The [documentation](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html) for `hyperref` reads:

> `hypertexnames` -- boolean -- use guessable names for links
>
> `naturalnames` -- boolean -- use LaTeX-computed names for links

And that's it. A [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3188/8057) addresses the meaning of `hypertexnames` -- is `naturalnames` even a third naming scheme, or does `naturalnames=true` imply `hypertexnames=false`?

Perhaps related: Does this setting affect compatibility with other packages? Is it advisable to always include `hyperref` after all other packages, or are there exceptions?

Comment: For the last question, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `naturalnames` option makes a difference when the `hypertexnames` option is set to `true` (which is the case by default). Essentially, setting the former to `true` *may* be useful if you are using a package that

1. adds a cross-reference element (e.g. a new float type)
2. is not allowed for by the `hyperref` package
3. does not, itself, allow for the `hyperref` package.

To quote from the [documented source code](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.pdf) of the `hyperref` package:

> Anything which can be referenced advances some counter; […]. This means that classes or packages which introduce new elements need to define an equivalent `\theH<name>` for every `\the<name>`. We do make a trap to make `\theH<name>` be the same as `\arabic{<name>}`, if `\theH<name>` is not defined, but this is not necessarily a good idea. Alternatively, the `naturalnames` option uses whatever LaTeX provides, which may be useable. But then it’s up to you to make sure these are legal PDF and HTML names.

Comment: Later in the text it reads: "The `hypertexnames=false` option just makes up arbitrary names." Does this mean that `naturalnames=false,hypertexnames=false` is a sensible default settings to produce documents that "just work" but where the anchor names don't mean anything? Where would I see the anchor names anyway?

Comment: @user946850: If `hypertexnames=false`, `naturalnames` has no meaning and the current link name (stored in `\@currentHref`) is not based on the value of a particular counter (such as `figure` or `table`), but on the value of the single internal counter `\Hy@linkcounter`. Obviously, this is the most elementary mode. Nonetheless, it should work as long as all computed link names are legal PDF and HTML names.

Comment: "...as long as all computed link names are legal PDF and HTML names": How can the link names created with `hypertexnames=false` be not legal PDF or HTML names? Is this possible in theory/practice?

Comment: @user946850: That’s a good point! In fact, I’m convinced now that they will always be legal.