# custom chapter numeration vs hyperref

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters

I wanted to change the chapter numeration in such a way that the introduction of my thesis has number `I` and the first chapter has number `1` and so on. So I changed the style of the numeration using Roman for the Introduction and Arabic for the other chapters in this way:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{chapter}
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}   %set the style to roman

\chapter{Introduction}
My amazing intro
\newpage

\setcounter{chapter}{0}                     %reset the chapter counter: here lies the problem, I guess
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}} %change style to arabic

\chapter{Chapter 1}
My first chapter
\newpage
\chapter{Chapter 2}
My second chapter.
\end{doument}
```

I got what I wanted: the numeration of section and equations in the intro. is of the type `I.1` and frot he chapter 1 I have `1.1`, but now the hyperref package makes some mess: since in this way the introduction and the first chater are, according to the internal numeration, *both* the chapter 1, references to section `1.1` is actually section `I.1` and so on.

To be clearer: when in the pdf I click on the reference to the section `1.1`, the link sends me to the section `I.1` in the introduction.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}` should work -- by the way.. the MWE is somewhat weird and does not compile due to `\input` statements

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks it works. I corrected the MWE, it should be fine now.

Comment: more information at [What does the hyperref option hypertexnames do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3188/579)

Comment: @cfr: yes it's a duplicate ... and something I was not aware of... the guy there got 22 upvotes :D

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Me neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the section/chapter numbers are manipulated, `hyperref` is 'confused' if `hypertexnames=true` is used (which is done by default). Specifying `hypertexnames=false` as option to `hyperref` package provides the correct bookmarks and links.

*Note* This solution does not address stuff like `\tolerance` etc.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\tolerance=1000
\hbadness=10000


\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{chapter}
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}   %set the style to roman
%\input{intro}
\section{Introduction}%
\newpage

\setcounter{chapter}{0}                     %reset the chapter counter: here lies the problem, I guess
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}} %change style to arabic

\chapter{First}
%\input{ch1}

%\newpage
\chapter{Second}
%\input{ch2}

\end{document}
```